# Correct grouping sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, lead

I am attempting to group some results in a table, by their id and name. For the group, I want to also select the next_id, the lead value of the next record that is part of the group. When I issue a query like this:

```
SELECT id, grade, name,
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC) as next_id
    FROM dbo.GRADES
    where name like '%alan%'
    order by name ASC, id asc;
```

I get this result, which is what I **expect**

```
28273   100 alan-jones  28274
28274   100 alan-jones  28275
28275   100 alan-jones  28276
28276   200 alan-jones  28280
28280   100 alan-jones  28281
28281   100 alan-jones  28282
28282   100 alan-jones  NULL
```

NULL specifies that the results above have no next record to point to.

However, when I run this query on more people than alan, i.e without the where clause:

```
SELECT id, grade, name,
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC) as next_id
    FROM dbo.GRADES
    order by name ASC, id asc;
```

I get the following results, that I did **not** **expect**

```
28277   100 mike-cools  28278
28278   100 mike-cools  28283
28283   200 mike-cools  28284
28284   200 mike-cools  28279
28279   200 mike-cools  28273
28273   100 alan-jones  28274
28274   100 alan-jones  28275
28275   100 alan-jones  28276
28276   200 alan-jones  28280
28280   100 alan-jones  28281
28281   100 alan-jones  28282
28282   100 alan-jones  NULL
```

The row in particular that is causing the problem for me is:

```
28279   200 mike-cools  28273
28273   100 alan-jones  28274
```

This row should read:

```
28279   200 mike-cools  NULL
28273   100 alan-jones  28274
```

I cannot figure out as to how I can alter my query to group correctly, and not point to the next_id if the group is not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **partition** your `lead` call by the name, not **order** by it

```
SELECT   id, grade, name,
         LEAD(id) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ASC) as next_id
         -- Here -------^
FROM     dbo.GRADES
ORDER BY name ASC, id asc;
```

Comment: ah, that was it

Comment: if I do an order by in the lead function, wouldn't I want the same order by in the last statement of the main function?

Comment: @angryip: You *can* use `PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name ASC, id ASC`, but as there is just one name per partition, it's superfluous.

Comment: @angryip yup, what Thorsten said.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.